# Ruby Rspec3 expect to receive once call to for an internal method

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I want to try to test if an object use an optimisation in a particular case. So I have this sort of code

```
 class Bar
  attr_reader :n
  def initialize(n)
    @n=n
  end

  def a
    if @n <= 3
      b1
    else
      b2
    end
  end

  def b1
    @n+=1
  end

  def b2
    @n+=1 ##super fast addition
  end
end
```

I try to write a rspec like that

```
bar=Bar.new(5)
allow(bar).to receive(:b2).and_call_original

bar.a
expect(bar).to receive(:b2).once
expect(bar.n).to eq 6
```

But it doesn't work... Do you kown is it possible ? and if yes how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place `receive` expectation **before** the method invocation. Also you can merge `allow` and `expect` into a single line:

```
bar = Bar.new(5)
expect(bar).to receive(:b2).once.and_call_original
bar.a
expect(bar.n).to eq 6
```